# Proving that a set is closed using a proof by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-writing

I have to write a proof in which I have to prove that a certain set, say $A$, is closed (we are in $\mathbb R^1$ for this proof). I want to argue by contradiction so, I say, "Assume for contradiction, that $A$ is open." Now, I show that the assumption of $A$ being an open set leads to a contradiction (as desired). **Then, am I correct in concluding that $A$ is closed?** I am thinking that this might not be entirely accurate/rigorous since $A$ can also be half open and half closed but I am not entirely sure of this argument. In the back of my mind, I was also thinking about the fact that the complement of an open set must be closed but I don't think this fact is totally relevant here (expect for maybe providing some intuition).

Comment: You could assume for contradiction that $A$ is not closed.  There are sets that are open but not closed (e.g., open intervals), sets that are closed but not open (e.g., closed intervals), sets that are neither (e.g., half-open intervals), and sets that are both (e.g., $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$) in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A set is not open doesn't mean that it is closed. You need to show that $A$ equals it's closure.

So you can use the method of the contradiction by assuming that a limit point lies outside the set $A$ and showing that it can't hold given the description of the set.

Comment: Many a teacher has said that "If A is not closed then A is open" is true if A is a door. And a space in which every subset is open or closed (or both) is actually called a Door Space.

Comment: Ok this is a new term that I have learned from your comment. Thanks. In this question the context was in $\Bbb R$ that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is not closed does **not** imply $A$ is open (think about $\Bbb Q$ in the reals which is neither open or closed, or $[0,1)$, or many other sets). You **could** conclude from $A$ is not closed that there is some $x \notin A$ such that every open neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, and this could give you to some leverage to get a contradiction. Such an $x$ would be a point of $A^\complement$ that is not an interior point of $A^\complement$, so in that sense we're using that the *complement* of $A$ is not open, which is a valid deduction from $A$ being not closed.